# how to set min month at bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a web application which requires a month/year date to be entered.Currently i am using  bootstrap datepicker to show the month of the year.

```
var minDate = new Date();
minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth()-1, 1);
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
      minDate: minDate,
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    viewMode: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
});
```

The code above allow the user to select previous month or last month.How can i restrict the user to select previous month or last month by modify the code above?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/1676/)

Comment: What about reading the DOC: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#id6  ??? And i don't get the purpose of posting {non working/badly configured} jsFiddle

Comment: The fiddle is broken/doesn't demonstrate the problem and the docs have it stated quite clearly how to enable/configure this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a selectable range, using `startDate` and `endDate`

For further info, on the available options, check the docs **[https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html](http://here)**